# Syncfusion PdfViewer - Load data directly from blob

Tags: angular, typescript, syncfusion

My question is how to load pdf directly from blob. I don't want to make call to API to get response. The problem is that code belowe make a call to api on /load. Why and how can i avoid it?

Typescript:

```
  public service = 'http://localhost:4200/api/';
  public load() {
    this.gdvService.getData(this.data.id, this.data.configuration)
    .subscribe(gdvData => {
      const responseData = gdvData[this.data.configuration.dataColumn];
      const blob = new Blob([responseData], { type: 'application/pdf' });
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        const base64data = reader.result;
        const pdfviewer = (document.getElementById('pdfViewer') as any).ej2_instances[0];
        pdfviewer.load(base64data, null);
      };
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```html
<ejs-pdfviewer id="pdfViewer" [serviceUrl]='service' style="height:640px;display:block"></ejs-pdfviewer>
```

Answer (score 0):

Syncfusion PDF Viewer control is both server and the client side oriented. PDF viewer control processes the PDF document in the server side(developed with .NET environment) and send the processed PDF data to the client using the web service to render the PDF document and for further operations in PDF viewer.  So, currently it not possible to load the PDF document in PDF Viewer without sever side.

Regards, 
Akshaya